# Animation only works on first element when using Var CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have found a lovely button animation and implemented it using a tutorial from [this](https://youtu.be/WOSaNbpHNqU) video. The button animation works on the first button, however not properly on the second.

It uses JavaScript and CSS var() to generate an animation, both of which I am not familiar with.

HTML and JavaScript is as follows, Run Snippet to see what I mean:

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* color: rgb(11, 81, 211); */
  border: 2px solid rgb(11, 81, 211);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn span {
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-right: 50%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(11, 81, 211);
}

.btn span:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(11, 81, 211);
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button1"><span>Plot</span></button>
  <script>
    const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
      const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
      const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

      btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
      btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
    }
  </script>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button2"><span>Plot</span></button>
  <script>
    const btn2 = document.querySelector('.btn');
    btn2.onmousemove = function(e) {
      const x = e.pageX - btn2.offsetLeft;
      const y = e.pageY - btn2.offsetTop;

      btn2.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
      btn2.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

I have tried renaming the function, the var() etc. but with no luck.
Perhaps I could use Id's and pass to the CSS, but I am struggling to find a method that would allow a dynamic number of buttons to be created.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: How exactly does the second button behave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use different selectors for your buttons, or just use `querySelectorAll()` and loop inside all btns and attach the event to all of them.

```
.btn {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* color: rgb(11, 81, 211); */
  border: 2px solid rgb(11, 81, 211);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn span {
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-right: 50%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(11, 81, 211);
}

.btn span:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(11, 81, 211);
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover::before {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  color: white;
}


<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button1"><span>Plot</span></button>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button2"><span>Plot</span></button>
  <script>
    const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn');
    for(let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
      btns[i].onmousemove = function(e) {
        const x = e.pageX - btns[i].offsetLeft;
        const y = e.pageY - btns[i].offsetTop;

        btns[i].style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
        btns[i].style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
     }
   }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and works a charm! Thank you very much indeed

Answer (score 2):

You need to give a different classname in the second button and also need to add the css of that class. Here is your solution

```css
.btn, .btn-2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-flex;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: #ffffff;
  /* color: rgb(11, 81, 211); */
  border: 2px solid rgb(11, 81, 211);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.btn span, .btn-2 span {
  padding-left: 50%;
  padding-right: 50%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: rgb(11, 81, 211);
}

.btn span:hover, .btn-2 span:hover {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.btn::before, .btn-2::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: var(--y);
  left: var(--x);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(11, 81, 211);
  transition: width 0.5s, height 0.5s;
}

.btn:hover::before, .btn-2:hover::before {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 1200px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button1"><span>Plot</span></button>
          <script>
            const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
            btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
              const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
              const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;
        
              btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
              btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
            }
          </script>
        </div>
        
        <div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn-2" id="button2"><span>Plot</span></button>
          <script>
            const btn2 = document.querySelector('.btn-2');
            btn2.onmousemove = function(e) {
              const x = e.pageX - btn2.offsetLeft;
              const y = e.pageY - btn2.offsetTop;
        
              btn2.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
              btn2.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
            }
          </script>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This method makes it difficult to have an arbitrary number of buttons through Javascript

Comment: Ah ok. Could you suggest an alternative script?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that in both scripts you use `document.querySelector('.btn')` which selects the first element which in the tree which has the `.btn` class and that is button1. You should rather user `document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0]` for button1 and `document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[1]` for button2 as shown bellow:

```
<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button1"><span>Plot</span></button>
  <script>
    const btn2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[0];
    btn.onmousemove = function(e) {
      const x = e.pageX - btn.offsetLeft;
      const y = e.pageY - btn.offsetTop;

      btn.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
      btn.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
    }
  </script>
</div>

<div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn" id="button2"><span>Plot</span></button>
  <script>
    const btn2 = document.getElementsByClassName('btn')[1];
    btn2.onmousemove = function(e) {
      const x = e.pageX - btn2.offsetLeft;
      const y = e.pageY - btn2.offsetTop;

      btn2.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
      btn2.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
    }
  </script>
</div>
```